# How to make integer array of id's inside strings.xml?

Tags: android, xml, resources

I am new at Android development. I want to make an app that have a module in which I displayed certain text files over text View. And I store these files in Raw folder, but I want to declare those files id's as arrays in Strings.xml so that I can save my efforts.
I saw some people referencing as @drawable/filename but @Raw/filename is giving error. Can anyone give me assist to get out of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you just need to declare array in your `styles.xml`

```
 <int-array name="ids">
            <item>1</item>
            <item>2</item>
            <item>3</item>
            <item>4</item>
            <item>45</item>
            <item>5</item>
        </int-array>
```

And to access it

```
String [] mIdsArray= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ids);
```

This method is to read raw file

```
public static String readRawTextFile(Context ctx, int resId)
{
    InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
    String line;
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return text.toString();
}
```

use the above code in your project,
Thanks!

Comment: I want to give references to the ID's of text files as item